# sum up columns based on query output

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Currently the query below gives me the output in the graph under it.

```
Select c.campaign_id, sum(case medium when 'photo' then 1 else 0 end) Photo, sum(case medium when 'story' then 1 else 0 end) Story, sum(case medium when 'video' then 1 else 0 end) Video, sum(case medium when 'album' then 1 else 0 end) Carousel
From `public_collaboration_contents` as cc 
Left join `public_collaborations` as c ON cc.collaboration_id = c.id
Left join `public_influencers` as i on c.influencer_id = i.id
Left join `public_collaboration_tasks` as ct on cc.id = ct.collaboration_content_id
Where cc.state = 'delivered'
And ct.state = 'delivered'
Group by c.campaign_id
```

| campaign_id | photo | story | video | carousel |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |

I would like it to look like this instead

| campaign_id | Total content |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 8 |

how can i change the query so it does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select c.campaign_id, sum(case when medium in ('photo', 'story', 'video', 'album') then 1 else 0 end) Total
```

or just simply (if no other media values rather than above four)

```
Select c.campaign_id, count(*) Total
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `countif()`:

```
Select c.campaign_id, countif(medium in ('photo', 'story', 'video', 'album')) as total
```